# Expectation value of an arbitrary observable. My own definition and `cirq` limitations

Tags: programming, quantum-algorithms, circuit-construction, cirq

In [my previous question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/16849/multiplying-quantum-circuits-in-cirq-using-and-computing-expectation-values) I was struggling with the definition of expectation value of an observable for a circuit. Here is what I have derived after some support (I simplify the definition to 2-qubit system (+3rd ancilla)):

**My Definition.** Given a 2-qubit circuit $C$ and a 2-qubit observable $Ob$, the expectation value of $Ob$ for $C$ is defined as $$EV(C, Ob):=\sqrt{\sum_{ij}|\alpha_{ij0}|^2} - \sqrt{\sum_{ij}|\alpha_{ij1}|^2},$$
where $\alpha_{ijk}$ are such that $$(Ob_X\circ(C\otimes I))|000⟩=\sum_{ijk}\alpha_{ijk}|ijk⟩,$$
where $Ob_X$ denotes X-Axis control, i.e. $Ob_X=(I\otimes H)\circ Ob_C\circ(I\otimes H)$, where $Ob_C$ denotes $Ob$ controlled by the ancilla qubit.

[image]

My question is whether this definition is correct. If so, why does `cirq` constrain `simulate_expectation_values` method only for observables being Pauli Strings (tensor product of Pauli Gates)?

---

After @Craig Gidney answer I thought it would be easy to write (just using `cirq` and `numpy`) a code that computes expectation value with regard to arbitrary observable and I derived the following snippet:

```
import cirq
from copy import deepcopy
from cirq import X, CZ, H, Circuit, Simulator, GridQubit, InsertStrategy
import numpy as np

def example_circuit(q0, q1):
    sqrt_x = X ** 0.5
    yield sqrt_x(q0), sqrt_x(q1)
    yield CZ(q0, q1)
    yield sqrt_x(q0), sqrt_x(q1)

def extend_circ(C, Ob):
    circ = deepcopy(C)
    q2 = GridQubit(2, 0)
    ObC = Ob.controlled_by(q2)
    circ.append([H(q2), ObC, H(q2)], strategy=InsertStrategy.NEW_THEN_INLINE)
    return circ

def main():
    q0 = GridQubit(0, 0)
    q1 = GridQubit(1, 0)

    C = Circuit(example_circuit(q0, q1))
    Ob = cirq.X(q0) * cirq.X(q1)
    # Ob = cirq.X(q0)*cirq.X(q1) + 0.1 * cirq.Z(q0) * cirq.Z(q1)

    ext_circ = extend_circ(C, Ob)
    print(ext_circ)
    result = Simulator().simulate(ext_circ)
    print(result)
    p0 = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.abs(result.final_state_vector[::2])**2))
    p1 = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.abs(result.final_state_vector[1::2])**2))
    expectation_value = p0 - p1
    print('Expectation Value: {}'.format(expectation_value))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Which gives the following output obtained from prints:

```
(0, 0): ───X^0.5───@───X^0.5───────PauliString(+X)───────
                   │               │
(1, 0): ───X^0.5───@───X^0.5───────X─────────────────────
                                   │
(2, 0): ───────────────────────H───@─────────────────H───
measurements: (no measurements)
output vector: 0.5|000⟩ + 0.5j|010⟩ + 0.5j|100⟩ + 0.5|110⟩
Expectation Value: 0.9999999403953552
```

However, if I uncomment `# Ob = cirq.X(q0)*cirq.X(q1) + 0.1 * cirq.Z(q0) * cirq.Z(q1)` I obtain the error `AttributeError: 'PauliSum' object has no attribute 'controlled_by'` which indicates that in order to apply my method an observable must be "controlable".

**My naive question.** Maybe it would be easier to make in `cirq` all observables controlable by definition (i.e. extend `controlled_by` method to all observables)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why does cirq constrain simulate_expectation_values method only for observables being Pauli Strings

It's certainly not a *necessary* constraint. But a reason a library would do Pauli products *first* is that they are simple, pretty flexible, and widely used. For example, they're easy to measure on hardware (only single qubit operations needed) and they're the basis of the stabilizer formalism.

A good contribution to Cirq would be to generalize this method to work on `cirq.PauliSum` observables like `cirq.X(q1)*cirq.X(q2) + 0.1 * cirq.Z(q1) * cirq.Z(q2)`. Cirq doesn't really have a more general definition of observable than that at the moment IIRC.

Comment: I just naively tried to implement this method on all circuits and observables (see above) and I find out that `controlled_by` method do not apply to observable like `cirq.X(q0)*cirq.X(q1) + 0.1 * cirq.Z(q0) * cirq.Z(q1)`. Wouldn't be easier to make all observables controllable?

Comment: @FallenApart The meaning of a control can get a bit hairy when you're dealing with observables that are also unitary matrices such as Paulis. There's an ambiguity in whether or not the measurement result should be 0 or +1 when the control isn't satisfied, and this ambiguity interacts with other conventions in cirq. I'd consider adding `controlled_by` to PauliSum to be a complex software engineering challenge, because of the need to resolve these ambiguities in a satisfying way. Probably not as bad as trying to define what it means to control a Kraus operator, though.

Comment: @FallenApart There's also issues of closure. For example, you wouldn't just be defining `(X(a) + Y(b)).controlled_by(c)` you'd also want to define `(X(a).controlled_by(d) + Y(b)).controlled_by(c)`. And you'd want to make sure that e.g. controlling before converting to a PauliSum was consistent with controlling afterward. I wouldn't be surprised if there's some contradiction in behavior hiding in this system when you try to generalize what it means to control these things.

Comment: I believe it is straightforward from theoretical point of view. If we have any linear operator $Q\in H(\mathbb{C}^{2n})$ and we want to condition it by ancilla qubit appended at the beginning, then it is just direct sum of identity operator and $Q$, i.e. $I_{\mathbb{C}^2}\oplus Q$. It materializes in matrix representation a block matrix (like in the wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_logic_gate#Controlled_(CX_CY_CZ)_gates). And since the operation of direct sum is linear, we precisely obtain what you called closure. And thus, it is well defined for linear combinations of operators.

Comment: And from software engineering point of view I don't know yet why `cirq.ops.PauliSum` class is not a child of `cirq.ops.Operation`.

Comment: @FallenApart That definition works fine for reversible operations, but PauliSum can also represent irreversible operations like amplitude damping and dephasing and the representations of these operations are not in an unambiguous form that you can apply a direct sum to. The reason PauliSum is not an operation is because it can represent things that aren't valid quantum operations. For example, 0*cirq.X(q) is not a trace preserving quantum channel.

Comment: Direct sum can be applied to any linear mappings. I should have written $L(\mathbb{C}^2)$ instead of $H(\mathbb{C}^2)$. Thus, such conditioning works for zero mapping as well.

Comment: @FallenApart Try to apply the direct sum to a Kraus operator and see what happens. If you distribute over the operator's terms, the resulting operation violates the sum-to-identity condition. it might be useful if you actually tried to implement what you're saying will work, and then I can point out specifically where the implementation blows up. Explicit code is nice at clarifying things like that.

Comment: I guess I get the point why PauliSum is not an Operation. Does `cirq.ops.Operation` are precisely Qantum operations in wiki (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_operation) sense? Cirq nomenclature unfortunetely does not clarify it.

Comment: @FallenApart A cirq operation is an object that can be placed into a quantum circuit. It's not *technically* required to be well formed in any sense (you just won't be able to simulate the circuit) but internally we don't make something an operation unless it works with the simulators.

Comment: I do not claim that direct sum of identity and Kraus operator have any desired properties, because I am not sure what `desired` would mean. I am just claiming that conditioning on Operations is a natural definition which can be straightforward extended to any linear operator. And you are right, I should support my claim with some code. Thanks again for all explanations, they help a lot!